# How to turn html to pdf using jspdf

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, jspdf

The demo for jspdf (http://mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/) shows a call fromHTML.  It says it is early, so I expected potential bugs and things not working, but what I get is:

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.fromHTML($('body').get(0), 15, 15, {'width': 155});
doc.save("test.pdf");
```

Typeerror: doc.fromHTML is not a function

Pasting the exact code from the demo fails with the same message.  Why is the function not there?

Comment: can you provide fiddle ?

Comment: jsfiddle.net go there create your problem there and provide me the link @Dov